# separation of files on the basis of their name

Tags: shell-script

I have a folder containing lots of files like 3 lac plus files. I have to separate them according to their names in three different folders. e.g. a few names are:

```
7msf_stem_0_mcannotate.pdb
7msf_loop_3_mcannotate.pdb
6tna_strand_10_mcannotate.pdb
7msf_strand_4_mcannotate.pdb
```

I have to keep all the files containing "stem" in their name in one folder called stem, those containing "loop" in their names in another folder called `loops`, while those containing "strand" in their name called `strands`.

Is there a shell script to do that?

Comment: Well, there will be a shell script if you program it.

Comment: well that was quite helpful lol.. actually I am quite new to linux and I need to solve this problem. I need some help thats the sole purpose of posting this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
 mkdir ../loops ../stems ../strands
 for x in loop stem strand
 do
    mv *${x}* ../${x}s
 done
```

please note that dirs will be on a parent folder.